# Соединение подсетей

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-xp, маршрутизатор

Создал виртуальную машину virtual box с Windows 2003,
в настройках virtual box подсоединил к внутренней сети.

Настроил локальную сеть на этой машине:

> ip 10.1.2.14 mask 255.255.255.0 host 10.1.2.1

Создал виртуальную машину virtual box с Windows XP,
в настройках virtual box подсоединил к внутренней сети и к виртуальному адаптеру хоста.

Настроил внутреннюю сеть:

> ip 10.1.2.1 mask 255.255.255.0

Настроил сеть с виртуальным адаптером:

```
ip 10.1.1.1
 mask 255.255.255.0
```

В cmd ввел:

> route add 10.1.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1  route add 10.1.2.0
>   MASK 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.1

Настроил windows 10 на "настоящем компьютере":

> ip 10.1.1.10  mask 255.255.255.0

В итоге на ping

> с 10.1.2.14 10.1.1.10

отвечает, а на ping с

> 10.1.1.10 10.1.2.14

нет и на ping

> с 10.1.1.10

не отвечает

> 10.1.1.1

Все ли я настроил правильно?